# Google geocoding API Inner Workings

Tags: machine-learning, google-api, gis, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm currently working with some large datasets that include some location based information but lack direct latitude and longitude measurements which I need in order to create visualizations.

In order to resolve this problem, I've been using geocoding APIs that require addresses or address-like information as input and provide latitude and longitude information as output.

I started by using the [Nominatim](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) API.  Unfortunately, due to the nature of the address-like data that I have, many of my queries failed so I started using the [Google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_315916117595-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7E%20Google%20Maps%20Geocoding%20API-KWID_43700039136946117-kwd-300650646186-userloc_9021435&utm_term=KW_google%20geocoding%20api-ST_google%20geocoding%20api&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0f6b0riq6gIVRr7ACh2J9QJ2EAAYASAAEgIvvvD_BwE). The Google API provided me with a significantly higher success rate, but it is a paid API which is not ideal.

I realize that given the incredible resources that Google has that it would be virtually impossible to build a system that rivals their geocoding API within a reasonable amount of time, but it's made me wonder what's going on under the hood.

Is a BERT-like translational system at work? What happens to the text after it's sent off?

Comment: I was unable to find public references to Google using BERT in the Place Search or Geocoding API, or to anything regarding "what happens to the text after it's sent off", really. However, given Google's history in search, it's not unlikely they will apply their text search techniques (BERT or otherwise) to correct misspellings or otherwise adapting the input query to recognize synonyms, etc, which would explain the higher hit rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using n-grams for similar usage by creating an index and an inverted index. See this package [ngram](https://pypi.org/project/ngram/)

```py
import ngram 
...

country = filename.replace('.csv', '')
ind[country] = ngram.NGram()
inv[country] = {}
s_csv = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=';')
next(s_csv)
for row in s_csv:
    coord = tuple(map(float, row[0:2]))
    ad = ' '.join(row[2:]).lower()
    ind[country].add(ad)
    inv[country][ad] = (coord, address)
```

then you can use the `find` function

Take care of the memory consumption ~16GB RAM for a country like France and OSM Data

To see an implementation of that, check this [OpenGeoCode HTTP API Service source code](https://github.com/scampion/)